# Java server receiving large data over TCP slower than expected

Tags: java

I'm writing a simple TCP server in java to receive image data from a client and then process it. The client is connected to the server over a 25Gbit network but the data transfer speed is limited around 4.5Gbit/s.

The client (winserv 2016) is recording data from an sCMOS camera at 100fps (8MB each frame) and then write the data directly to the TCP socket. The server (Centos7) then read the data and write it out. The server read data image by image. The downstream disk writing throughput is not the issue since I tried without writing the data out and see the same kind of performance. Using `iperf` between the windows client and linux server gives the expected bandwidth (20+ Gbit/s). Is this normal to have such a bit network speed difference between `iperf` and TCP traffic ?

```java
private void writefile(int zsize,int ysize,int xsize,String filename,int port) throws IOException{
    InetAddress add = InetAddress.getByName(config.ipadd);
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port, 10, add);
    Socket clientsocket;
    clientsocket = socket.accept();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(clientsocket.getInputStream()));
    int chunksize = 2*xsize*ysize;
    byte[] frame = new byte[chunksize];
    long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i=0;i<zsize;i++){
        int pos = 0;
        while (pos<chunksize-1){
            int len = in.read(frame,pos,chunksize-pos);
            pos+= len;
        }
        fos.write(frame);
    }
    fos.close();
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    printlock.lock();
    System.out.println((long)zsize*(long)xsize*(long)ysize*2d/(double)(t1-t0));
    System.out.printf("Data transfer speed: %f MB/s\n", (long)zsize*(long)xsize*(long)ysize*2d/((double)(t1-t0)/1000d)/1024d/1024d);
    printlock.unlock();
    in.close();
    socket.close();
    clientsocket.close();
    try{
        ports.put(port);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException it){
        it.printStackTrace();
    }
    return;
}
```

I have also tried to use the `nio` approach (following the example from https://pzemtsov.github.io/2015/01/19/on-the-benefits-of-stream-buffering-in-Java.html). However the performance is rather similar.

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.ByteChannel;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;

public class datagetter {
    private static ByteBuffer buf;
    private String hostname = null;
    private int port = 0;
    private int framesize = 2048*2048;
    private int numframe = 500;
    private static void ensure (int len, ByteChannel chan) throws IOException
    {
        if (buf.remaining () < len) {
            buf.compact ();
            buf.flip ();
            do {
                buf.position (buf.limit ());
                buf.limit (buf.capacity ());
                chan.read (buf);
                buf.flip ();
            } while (buf.remaining () < len && buf.limit()!=buf.capacity());
        }
    }
    public datagetter(String hostname, int port,int framesize,int numframe){
        this.hostname = hostname;
        this.port = port;
        this.framesize = framesize;
        this.numframe = numframe;
    }
    public void receiveandwrite(String filename) throws IOException{
        buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(framesize);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        ServerSocketChannel chanserv = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        chanserv.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(hostname,this.port));
        SocketChannel chan = chanserv.accept();
        buf.limit(0);
        byte[] msg = new byte[framesize];
        for (int i=0;i<numframe;i++){
            ensure(framesize,chan);
            buf.get(msg,0,framesize);
            fos.write(msg);
        }
        chanserv.close();

        fos.close();
    }
}
```

I understand that there would be network protocol overhead when comparing `iperf` to real data transfer but I'm not sure why the throughput discrepancy is so large. Is this normal to expect such a big network speed difference?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've included a question at the end.

Comment: Your camera said to produce 800MB per second, which is around 6.5Gbit. I would be surprised if it took all of your channel in that setup. That transfer speed seems fitting for an image stream with some compression. There's also not enough information on how your measured.